# Use string as argument in a bash scipt

Tags: bash, terminal, vlc

Trying to write a script that use vlc to create a playlist.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=/media/*/*.mp3
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
   case $1 in
       -f | --filepath )       shift
                               filename=$1
                               ;;
       -h | --help )           usage
                               exit
                               ;;
       * )                     usage
                               exit 1
   esac
   shift
done
#echo $filename
vlc $filename  --novideo --quiet
```

This script is working but it only finds mp3 files in the root of any usb device. So i want to change the filename variable. This code gives similar results but it lists evething.

```
filename=$(find /media/* -name *.mp3 -print)
filename=$(tr '\n' ' ' <<<$filename)
```

Now the problem is that i can't pass it as an argument. I tried:

```
vlc $filename --novideo --quiet
or
vlc $*filename --novideo --quiet
or
vlc "$filename" --novideo --quiet
```

nothing worked. Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

Guys the problem I want help with is how to make vlc accept the filename variable as argument or arguments of files to use in the playlist. filename contains

```
/media/MULTIBOOT/Linkin Park - In The End.mp3 /media/MULTIBOOT/Man with a  
Mission ft. Takuma - Database.mp3 /media/MULTIBOOT/Sick Puppies - You're
Going Down.mp3 /media/MULTIBOOT/Skillet - Rise.mp3 /media/MULTIBOOT/Song
Riders - Be.mp3 /media/MULTIBOOT/30 Seconds to Mars - This is War.mp3  
/media/MULTIBOOT/Fade - One Reason.mp3
```

Now this is a string how to use it file path arguments?

Comment: Guys don't worry about the argument handling, what i want to know is how to make the final line work

Answer (score 3):

I would use bash's recursive globbing and arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar nullglob
files=()
while [[ $1 ]]; do
   case $1 in
       -f | --filepath )       shift
                               files+=("$1")
                               ;;
       -h | --help )           usage
                               exit
                               ;;
       * )                     usage
                               exit 1
   esac
   shift
done
if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
    files=( /media/**/*.mp3 )
    if [[ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "no mp3 files found"
        exit 1
    fi
fi
#printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"
vlc "${files[@]}"  --novideo --quiet
```

With this code, you can specify `-f filename` multiple times to play a few songs.

Comment: Note that `globstar` requires `bash` 4 or later. Prior to that, you would need a recursive shell function to walk the hierarchy yourself.

Comment: I want the deafult functionality of this script to be running without arguments and the arguments to be used only in certain situations

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis, that's why I check if the size of the array is zero (no command line options), and if so then check your /media directory

Comment: @glennjackman you are write but my code also finds if there are any mp3 is the usb devices. If there aren't any the find command won't return anything. The problem is that it does but i cannot pass the result as an argument in vlc. But your are also write a have to check it so i don't create an empty instance of vlc

Comment: Two (very minor) remarks: 1. before `files+=( "$1" )` you should check whether there is a positional parameter: `(($#)) || { usage; exit 1; }`or similar. 2. The `vlc` call should rather be `vlc --novideo --quiet -- "${files[@]}"`, so that no options can be passed to `vlc` (unless, of course, you want to allow this). Anyway, thanks for showing good Bash practice!

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote `*.mp3`. Otherwise it will be expanded in the current directory.

```
filename=$(find /media/* -name '*.mp3' -print)
```

You also don't need to remove the newlines. When you use the variable without quoting it, all whitespace, including newlines, will be converted to word delimiters.

Comment: Files with spaces or newlines in their names may break recognition of files, though.

Comment: They break the original version of the script, too.

Answer (score 1):

rather than storing all filenames in a variable, you can tell `find` to call an application with all the files. this will prevent problems with whitespace, newlines and the like:

```
 find /media -name '*.mp3' -exec vlc --novideo --quiet \{\} \+
```

Comment: it works but i want to store the file adresses for later use. The script is not final

Answer (score 1):

A better way to handle options in your script might be to use `getopts`, if you don't mind losing the option of long options.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while getopts vqt opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    f)  filename=($OPTARG) ;;
    h)  usage; exit 0 ;;
    *)  usage; exit 1 ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

filename=($(find /media/ -name \*.mp3 -type f))

vlc --novideo --quiet "${filename[@]}"
```

I don't know this usage of VLC, but the effect of this script is to create a command line with all the files found by the `find` command, which were stored in *array* called `$filename`.

An advantage of handling things in an array is that it lends itself to use in `for` loops.

```
for thisfile in "${filename[@]}"; do
   vlc "$thisfile" # with options to convert just one file
done
```

NOTE that since you're using bash, you may not need to use `find` at all.

```
shopt -s globstar
filelist=(/media/**/*.mp3)
```

Check `man bash` for discussion of `globstar`.

Comment: The `for` loop will run a separate `vlc` instance for each file, instead of loading all the files into one playlist.

Comment: Yes, it will. I include it in case there's some other processing that needs to be done on the files themselves. Personally, I'd aim to create separate playlists, then just point VLC at the playlist files.